# When using range function to populate list why do I get list formatting error when printing with %d?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning python and I'm a bit puzzled by some behavior of lists when I create one using the range function. Hopefully someone can help me wrap my head around this? Here is a block of code I wrote:

```
elements = []
elements.append(range(1, 6))
for number in elements:
    print "Line %d" % number
```

When I run this, I get the error for line 4:

TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list

If I re-write the code as such:

```
elements = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    elements.append(i)
for number in elements:
    print "Line %d" % number
```

it runs how I expected the first block would.

If I replace the %d with a %r, it prints the list as

Line [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

instead of printing each number on its own line.

When I directly append the range to the elements list is it somehow making a list of a list instead of iterated values like it does when using the for? 
With a little testing I got this:

```
>>> print range(1, 6)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> elements = []
>>> elements.append(range(1, 6))
>>> print elements
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Is this why it won't let me print the numbers using the %d formatter? How would I un-nest this list or access the contents of it? I'd be very grateful if someone could walk me through this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `range(1,6)` returns a list.  So `elements` looks like:
`[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]` and the first iteration of your for loop `number` = `elements[0]` = `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, which is a list.

If you do this, you will get what you expect:

```
elements = []
elements = range(1, 6)
for number in elements:
    print "Line %d" % numberr
```

Answer (score 4):

What's happening when you append a list to another list is that you'll get a nested list. Initially you had `elements = []`. In that list you appended another list (`range(1, 6)`) which makes it a list of a list.

```
>>> elements = []
>>> elements
[]
>>> elements.append(range(1, 6))
>>> elements
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

What you can do here is concatenate instead of appending by using the `+` operator (i.e. `elements + range(1, 6)`.

```
>>> elements = []
>>> elements
[]
>>> elements + range(1, 6)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.7, `range` returns a list. And [`append` method](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) adds an item to the end of the list.

So, when you write `elements.append(range(1, 6))`, `elements` is now a list with a single element (that is a list).

You may want to use

```
elements.extend(range(1,6)) # 'extend' append all elements of the given list
```

Or directly

```
elements = range(1,6)
```